# How to get the row index with min value and specific value with one statement

Tags: matlab

I want to get the minimum row index with specific value in a specific column.

For example,

```
ma = [8 1 4; 3 1 5; 1 2 4; 1 2 5] 


ma =

     8     1     4
     3     1     5
     1     2     4
     1     2     5
```

choosing second column (`col = 2`) and `val = 2`, as you can see second column has two elements with value of `2` and I want the one with minimum index (`index = 3`).

So far I've come up with,

```
[value1,index1]=min(ma(ma(:,col) == val,1))


value1 =

     1


index1 =

     1
```

Comment: `[val,ind] = min(ma(:,1:2))` what are your expected values? min value is `1` in both columns.

Comment: expected value is 3, I want to get the first match row index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use,

```
col = 2;
val = 2;
ind = min(find(ma(:,col)==val));
```

which will give `ind = 3`.

Comment: That's what I would have used. + 1

Comment: Thank you i find the solution. find(ma(:,2)==2&ma(:,1)==min(ma(ma(:,2)==2,1)),1)